# After installing zookeeper and kafka cluster and management monitoring tools on docker-compose, the management interface an error

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I tried the Baidu search exception problem to modify the configuration file according to netizens, but the problem was not resolved in the end

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, remember to properly use text formatting tools when writing both questions and answers

Comment: It would be useful if you could show your compose file